# Restart task tracker and job tracker service (task tracker and job tracker) in CDH4

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How do I restart the task trackers and job tracker using CDH4 from the command line?

I tried following given script but got error

> [root@adc1210765 bin]# ./stop-mapred.sh 
>   /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/bin/../conf no jobtracker to stop cat:
>   /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/bin/../conf/slaves: No such file or
>   directory

I want to restart all instance of tasktracker running at my cluster nodes

Comment: TT and JT are MapReduce services. You might want to replace HDFS with MapReduce in your title.

Answer (score 1):

You must do this on each of the task trackers

```
sudo service hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-tasktracker restart
```

And on the job tracker

```
sudo service hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-jobtracker restart
```

You can also use stop and start in place of restart. Might have to change your hadoop version number.

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_11_3.html?scroll=topic_11_3

Answer (score 0):

You can also try starting the JobTracker Daemon by

`/etc/init.d/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-jobtracker start`

and Task Tracker by

`/etc/init.d/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-tasktracker start`

Ensure the version number is appropiate.

Comment: There is no entry for hadoop-0.20-mapreduce under /etc/init.d

Comment: what version of hadoop are you running? and what command are you usually starting with?